# ADSL card for Cisco Router 1800 series

Tags: cisco, router, adsl

I need an internal ADSL card for Cisco Router 1800 series, Is there anyone who will help me ?

Comment: Where are you located?  May resellers here in North America

Comment: I live in Turkey, are they able to send ISTANBUL ?

Answer (score 1):

WIC-1ADSL or HWIC-1ADSL wll do the trick.

Max 8Mb/s with the wic, as it supports only adsl2, not 2+.

Hwics are more expensive, but supports faster speeds (~ 18Mb/s).

European sellers on ebay have cheap ones.